# How can I autorun photoswipe to show the first picture in the gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, photoswipe

I am trying to autorun photoswipe on pages that have a photoswipe gallery on them as soon as the page loads. I have tried two separate solutions, the first one looked something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    Code.photoSwipe('a', '#Gallery');
    Code.PhotoSwipe.Current.show(0);
}, false);
```

I couldn't find the documentation as to where I was supposed to put it, so I simply had that in separate  tags on the pages in question. The second one looked like this.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){   
    var myPhotoSwipe = $(".gallery li a").photoSwipe({
        jQueryMobile: true,
        loop: false,
        enableMouseWheel: false,
        enableKeyboard: false
    });
    myPhotoSwipe.show(0);      
});
```

Because the second is jQuery and my friend's site is made with WordPress, I wrapped it and used the appropriate id, but nothing happened. (I also double checked that i was putting the code in the right template actually finding the JS in the source code of the page.) But yeah still nothing.

If anyone could help me out they would literally save me hours of headache (and possibly my life) as I promised my friend that I would be able to do this.

Comment: do you get any error or it just not autorun? Maybe you can try to wrap the jQuery code inside a simple `$(document).ready()` function

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer, I had no errors it just didn't autorun. I just tried with a document ready function, and it didn't seem to work either.   I am very unfamiliar with jQuery so it might be a basic mistake that i'm making somewhere. :(